# How can I access derived base member from derived class?(in C++)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, binary-search-tree, derived

Base class is `Node`. `AvLNode` is derived from it.

In `AVLNode` when `this->Left()->Height()` is called for `Balancefactor()`,
`Left()` left* from class `Node` having no height is called.
It ends up with a segmentation fault.

Base class:

```
// A generic tree node class
template<class NodeType>
class Node {
  string key;
  NodeType* left;
  NodeType* right;
  NodeType* parent;
public:
  Node() { key="-1"; left=NULL; right=NULL; parent = NULL;};
  Node(NodeType* source) {  //Copy Constructor
    key=source->Key();left=source->Left();right=source->Right();parent=source->Parent(); 
};
void setKey(string aKey) { key = aKey; };
void setLeft(NodeType* aLeft) { left = aLeft; };
void setRight(NodeType* aRight) { right = aRight; };
void setParent(NodeType* aParent) { parent = aParent; };
string  Key() { return key; };
NodeType* Left() { return left; };
NodeType* Right() { return right; };
NodeType* Parent() { return parent; };
void copyData(NodeType* source){key=source->key;};
};
```

Derived class:

```
class AvlNode : public Node<AvlNode>
{
 int height;
 public:
 AvlNode(){height=1;};
 //~AvlNode();
 int Height() { return height; };
 int BalanceFactor(){
    return this->AvlNode::Left()->Height() - this->AvlNode::Right()->Height();
 };
 int setHeight(int aHeight){height=aHeight;};
};
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `left`, `right` and `parent` are all `NULL` in the code you've shown. So of course `Left()->Height()` crashes - you are trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: What is a 'derived base member'?

Comment: I've made use of this here :
please go through this:

https://github.com/tshrjn/ADSA

Comment: `this->AvlNode::Left()` is the same as `this->Left()` since you do not redefine `Left` in `AvlNode`

Comment: The line marked `//Copy Constructor` is not a copy constructor (that would look like `Node(Node const &)`

Comment: @TusharJain  I've proposed an answer to your question to make the function more robust.  But it appears that there are other important errors in the remaining of your github code that lead to memory corruption.  See remark in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an `AvlNode`, its constructor default initializes its base `Node`.  So the `left` and `right` pointers are both null.

Of course, it's possible that later you change it using `setLeft()` or `setRight()` but there's no guarantee that you do it.   Also in a tree structure, you always have leafs that have no left nor right. And not all the nodes will have a left and a right node.

So for reliable code, you must take into account the possibility of having `Left()` or `Right()` being null:

```
int BalanceFactor()
{
int hl=0, hr=0;               // value of height if no child

if (Left()) 
    hl = Left()->Height();    // only dereference the pointer if not null
if (Right())
    hr = Right()->Height(); 

return hl-hr; 
};
```

**Very important remarks not related to your question:**

Your codebase provided in comment on github contains important errors:

- in `addNode()` you don't always return a value: this might result in random node pointers being returned, causing memory corruption.  When you call recursively `addNode(...)` you shall in fact `return (addNode(...))`)
- same error in  `Tree::min()`,  `Tree::max()` and  `Tree::findNode()` also for recursive calls.
- and finally `Tree::Successor()` doesn't return antything if none of the if condition is true, that is if `thisKey` is null). I've added a `return thisKey;` at the end of this function.

Only after having corrected ll these errors, could I run the code without segfault.  Here a running extract of [bst.cpp and avl.cpp](http://goo.gl/JhO0gn), with a coupe of exclamation marks on the line I had to change.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your input, the link you've mentioned for modified files doesn't work. Could you mention some other link ?

And I really appreciate you putting in your precious time. Thanks Again ! :D